# Cloud Firebase Authentication Error: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions."

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Swift I am creating a mobile application using Firebase Authentication and Cloud Database. The authentication works perfectly fine with users logging in and out of the app. Where I am having problems is when loading and saving the user's non-private data to the cloud database. When initially solving this problem I only want users to be able access their own data instead of everyone's data too.

So, in my firebase console for the database rule, I had entered the following from the Firebase website: [Firebase Cloud Database Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth).

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

When using these rules, I get the error in Swift:

> Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}

However, when the user Id it not checked, such as:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

It works as expected. Or when manually inputting my own user Id:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == "...";
    }
  }
}
```

It works as expected too, but obviously I can't use my own Id for everyone else. Therefore I am stuck and not sure how to fix this issue. I have tried using different names for the collections and tried using a different name for the userId attribute, but both altercations achieved little success. Therefore, I believe that the problem is with the 'userId' path. But I am so lost I think for now I will have to go with the second rule set until I can find a solution.

Here is my code in swift for getting the user's data:

```
func getUserData(userEmail: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ documentID: String?, _ userType: UserType?, _ tokensUsed: Double?) -> ()) {
    var documentID: String = ""
    var userType: UserType = .free
    var tokensUsed: Double = 0
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            completionHandler(nil, nil, nil)
            return
        }
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            completionHandler(nil, nil, nil)
            return
        }
        
        snapshot.documents.map { document in
            documentID = document.documentID
            
            let documentUserEmail = document["userEmail"] as? String ?? ""
            if documentUserEmail == userEmail {
                let documentUserType = document["userType"] as? String ?? "free"
                if documentUserType == "premium" {
                    userType = .premium
                }
                
                let userTokens = document["tokensUsed"] as? Int ?? 0
                
                return completionHandler(documentID, userType, tokensUsed)
            }
        }
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        completionHandler(nil, nil, nil)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for creating the data:

```
func createUserData(userId: String, userEmail: String , completionHandler: @escaping (_ documentID: String?, _ userId: String?, _ userType: UserType?, _ tokensUsed: Int?) -> ()) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["userId": userId, "userEmail": userEmail, "lastLogin": Date(), "tokensUsed": 0, "userType": "free"]) { error in
        
        getUserData(userId: userId, userEmail: userEmail) {
            documentID, userType, tokensUsed in
            if documentID != nil {
                completionHandler(documentID!, userId, userType!, tokensUsed!)
            } else {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for updating the data:

```
func updateUserData(documentID: String, userId: String, userEmail: String, userTokens: Int, userType: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("users").document(documentID).updateData(["userId": userId, "userEmail": userEmail, "lastLogin": Date(), "tokensUsed": userTokens, "userType": userType])
}
```

Here is the database structure on firebase console (while hiding the email and userId):

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to show your application code.  We should be able to see that your code matches your rules, and that the user ID of the currently signed in user matches the ID of the document you're working with.  Without seeing these things, we can't know what's going wrong.

Comment: You likely need 2 documents a private user that requires the id and a public user that doesn’t

Comment: Please include the code you're using to read/write the data and and an example of your database structure so we know where you're writing to.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I have added the code from Swift and the database structure.

Comment: One thing to note; you should be handling errors before doing anything with the data within firebase closures in `db.collection("users").addDocument`. `if let error = error` should be the first thing so you can elegantly handle the error before executing other code that relies on the data being available.

Comment: Here's an issue `db.collection("users").getDocuments` - why are you attempting to get *all* of the documents in the users collection when you only really want to get *this* users document? That would cause a rules error since *this* user doesn't have access to other users documents. I think you would want to get only get this users document by specifying their uid in the `/users collection/this users uid` path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jay ! Good points, firstly, I will switch the code around such that the error is being handled first. And Secondly, as the `userId` is an attribute of each document, how would I specify in Swift to only search documents which hold the current user's `userId` in swift?

Comment: Ah. In Firestore it's often best practice to have a users collection with each users document being stored with the users uid as the documentId. That avoids a query altogether and enforces rules. It then becomes a simple task to read that users document once they log in; using async/await `let test = try await self.db.collection("users").document("uid_0").getDocument()` where self.db points to my Firestore and uid_0 is this users did. If that answers the question, let me know and I will post it as a formal answer.